# How to get hold of the data in the dataset and pass to label

Tags: c#, dataset

I want to show the result of the dataset in a label.

---

Result set of function: HYFY_UIResult

```
    myid       result
    test123    5C
```

---

```
//Clear any previous Def table
if (calcDataSet.Tables.Contains("DS_Result") == true)
{
    calcDataSet.Tables.Remove("DS_Result");
}


HYFY_UIResult(lanid, "H1", strtDt.ToString("01/MM/yyyy"), endDt.ToString("01/MM/yyyy"), conPer);
DataRow[] DRow;

if (calcDataSet.Tables["DS_Result"].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    labelFirstHRes.Text = "-";
}
else
    DRow = calcDataSet.Tables["DS_Result"].Select("myid = " + lanid);
    labelFirstHRes.Text = DRow[0]["result"].ToString();
```

The else part is failing, I am getting the error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'DRow'

I want the label to show the result ("5C"). thanks.

Comment: Try this : calcDataSet.Tables["DS_Result"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("myid") == ladid).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: hit this error: A local variable named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'x', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: The variable 'x' is already used in your code.  Change variable name to something else in the code I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother, simplest mistake. my ELSE doesn't have **curly brackets**. and the declaration of datarow to be moved inside.

```
//Clear any previous Def table
if (calcDataSet.Tables.Contains("DS_Result") == true)
{
    calcDataSet.Tables.Remove("DS_Result");
}


HYFY_UIResult(lanid, "H1", strtDt.ToString("01/MM/yyyy"), endDt.ToString("01/MM/yyyy"), conPer);


if (calcDataSet.Tables["DS_Result"].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    labelFirstHRes.Text = "-";
}
else
{   
    DataRow[] DRow;
    DRow = calcDataSet.Tables["DS_Result"].Select("myid = '" + lanid + "'");
    labelFirstHRes.Text = DRow[0]["result"].ToString();
}
```